# Ruby gem to paginate text into wrapping columns

Tags: arrays, ruby, text, formatting

Is there any simple gem or method to print an array (or CSV rows) as a text table, that automatically follows to the bottom line and then wraps to column 2, 3, etc. from the top as long as the terminal's width parameter hasn't been used up yet?

For example notice the aligned, space-efficient output of 'ls' (sorted top-down then left-right):

```
 # ls
30_os-prober                Documents         Pictures           sysadmin.geany  xorg.conf
avivotool.regdump_good.txt  Downloads         Public             Templates       xorg.conf.00
bin                         fbcmd_update.php  regdump_broke.txt  tmp
crontab.root@quant.txt      grub-mkconfig     stuck.packages     unity.log
Desktop                     Music             sync               Videos
```

I've been using the "text-table" gem eg.

```
  puts $csv_rows[1].to_a.transpose.to_table.align_column 2, :right
```

but it only prints 100's of lines vertically straight down, even though horizontally barely 30 chars might be used.  I would prefer the output to use that right side space for one or more columns of items that otherwise follow at the bottom of column 1.

Answer (score 0):

Experimented a bit. 
 One way I DON'T at all like, but get away with two-column mode only:

```
i=0; puts (sa=$csvrow.to_a.transpose.to_table.align_column(2, :right).to_s.split("\n") )[0..sa.size/2].map{|e| e + sa[(i+=1)+sa.size/2].to_s + "\n"}
```

All it really does is loop through the first half, from item i=0 to n/2, appending the item from i + n/2 (the second half) and a newline as it goes along.  The to_table keeps each item's string the same fixed length, so it all appears aligned in the end.  May be something to build upon.